# How to access angular Component from other Component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

in my Angular Application I try to access a Component, which I want to clone in an other component.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CloneComponentComponent } from './clone-component/clone-component.component'; // I want to access this component

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'UserManager';

  cloneUpper(){
    console.log("Cloned!");
    var cln = new CloneComponentComponent(); 
    console.log(cln);  //This returns CloneComponentComponent {}, so it is empty
    console.log(cln.toString()); //This return [object Object]
    var container = document.getElementById('cloneContainer');
    container?.append();
  }
}
```

As you can see the "cln" variable is empty but I do not really know how else I should access this component.

Comment: You have already asked the same question today. I would advise to finish the Angular tutorial before asking further, this is Angular basics really.

Comment: Hmmm you _don't_ import a component inside another component. You just don't. That's not how Angular works.

Comment: This is typically a XY problem. Problem X : you want to access the properties of a component from another component. You don't know how to do it, so you try something, like importing a component inside another. Angular doesn't work this way, so this fails (problem Y). Now instead of asking about your original problem X, you are asking about problem Y which you _believe_ will solve the problem X.